# What the political agenda of Fahr LLC?

Tags: united-states

According to [OpenSecrets](https://www.opensecrets.org/orgs/list.php?cycle=2014) Fahr LLC was is the organisation that put in the most money into the 2014 election cycle.

Where's their money coming from?
What kind of policy outcomes do they try to achieve?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Fahr LLC is privately owned by [Thomas Fahr Steyer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tom_Steyer), a billionaire hedge fund manager, environmentalist, and a leading Democratic fundraiser in the United States. It is likely a "shell" or wealth-holding company that serves no purpose other than to hold some of Steyer's assets.

Of the $75 million contributed by Fahr LLC during the 2014 election cycle, $67 million was given to [NextGen Climate Action](https://nextgenclimate.org/about/), a PAC which Steyer himself founded. The rest was donated to various Democratic organizations and Congressional candidates. No money was donated to Republican candidates.

Sources

- OpenSecrets - [Fahr LLC's Contribution distribution](http://www.opensecrets.org/orgs/summary.php?id=D000067344&cycle=2014#profileLeftColumn).
- OpenSecrets NextGen Climate Action - [donor list combines "Fahr LLC/Tom Steyer" as a single donor](http://www.opensecrets.org/527s/527cmtedetail_donors.php?ein=463201383&cycle=2014).

Comment: That's really interesting. I would be curious where you found that information.

Comment: @Philipp sources added.